# popup with draggable header only

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, draggable, modalpopup

I am using a modal popup in angular 5 and  set a property  **draggable="true"**

here is my model popup

```
 <div **draggable="true"** class="modal" id="addServiceProduct" role="dialog" [ngStyle]="{'display':addServiceModal}">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" id="draggable">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">
        {{this.editIndex>0?(this.viewProduct?'View Product':'Edit Product'):'Add Product'}} <span>-</span> {{serviceModel.Name}}
        <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" (click)="closeAddProduct()">
          <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      This is header
```

but i only want that header should be draggable not the entire popup so what are the possible solutions 
jquery .Draggable is not working in mytypescript.
please help

Comment: apply draggable true to header only

Comment: @justCode  not working I tried your solution also

Comment: Instead of jquery, can you try angular cdk [drag and drop feature](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview)? Its much more flexible